# extracting SIFT descriptors

Tags: opencv, sift

if you dont mind iam using opencv SIFT to get sift descriptors.
and i get the correct number of key-points and descriptors.

BUT when i loop through descriptors using code like this (iam accessing only the first descriptor)

```
for (int ii=0;ii<128;ii++)
    {
        int m=descriptors1.at<int>(0,ii);
            std::cout<<ii<<"    "<<m<<std::endl;
    }
```

i got stange values like
1110122255
4154646455
1101111115
1111020416

all of them are 10 digits and it is not possible ?
so what is the correct way to access those elements

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure descriptors are stored in a matrix of floating point values. Try using `float m = descriptors1.at<float>(0,ii)`